# Blackwell-MacQueen Urn Scheme

Tags: dirichlet-process

I'm having some difficulty understanding the steps in the proof in the bottom half of the second page of this paper: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281B-spring04/readings/blackwell-macqueen.pdf.

Specifically, let:

\begin{equation}
m_n(A)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+n}\mu(A)+\frac{1}{\alpha+n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\mathbb{I}(X_i\in A)},
\end{equation}

where $A$ is any subset of the probability space of $\mu$, and $\mu$ is any probability "base" measure.

We call a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a Polya sequence with parameters $\alpha>0$ and $\mu$ being any distribution, we have:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{P}\left(X_1\in A\right)=\mu(A),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1}\in A|X_1,\dots,X_n\right)=m_n(A).
\end{equation}

Also, let $I_j$ be the indicator of the event that $X_j$ is different from all $X_i$ with $i<j$ and define:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 &f_{nj}=I_jm_n(X_j),&\text{for }1\leq j\leq n,\\
 &f_{nj}=0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We want to prove that:
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq r\\x_j\in A}}{f_{nj}}\leq m_r(A),
\end{equation}
and that:
\begin{equation}
 m_r(A)\leq \sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq r\\x_j\in A}}{f_{nj}}+1-\sum_{1\leq j\leq r}{f_{nj}}.
\end{equation}

I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks, 
Anthony